# MPAndroidChart - Legend labels are being cut off

Tags: android, label, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Anybody has this problem? 
When I put the labels in BOTTOM position, these are cut.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They are cut because your **text is too long** and **the library does not support "wrapping"** of the labels to a new line.

You will either have to shorten your legend labels or implement the desired functionality yourself.

**UPDATE:**

Word wrapping for the `Legend` is now supported.

```
chart.getLegend().setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

Comment: this is not working with pie chart

Answer (score 52):

This seems to be a new [feature](https://github.com/danielgindi/MPAndroidChart/commit/bc8b7105d8f5f7260395bcd4023ab5ec77001710) since June (2015):

```
chart.getLegend().setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Should the legend word wrap? / this is currently supported only for:
 * BelowChartLeft, BelowChartRight, BelowChartCenter. / note that word
 * wrapping a legend takes a toll on performance. / you may want to set
 * maxSizePercent when word wrapping, to set the point where the text wraps.
 * / default: false
 * 
 * @param enabled
 */
public void setWordWrapEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mWordWrapEnabled = enabled;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I have solved for iOS   `chartView.legend.wordWrapEnabled = true;`

Comment: great ! you saved my time

Comment: **Note**: With MPAndroidChart allways watch out for the order of your calls. For `isWordWrapEnabled` you have to set it before setting the Data.

Answer (score 8):

Here I will show you an easy way by "Traditional Android Way", it's quite simple, my code is below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/i_am_chart_view_container"
    ...
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    .../>
```

Just need to add some `padding` to the container layout, or some `margin` to the chart view, and finally set `clipChildren`&`clipToPadding` to false.

**Result below:**

the blue area is padding or margin area.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You have to implement customize legends with their legends colours and lables
by following steps
**Step 1**

```
Legend legend = mChart.getLegend();
```

**Step 2**

```
int colorcodes[] = legend.Colors();
```

**Steps 3**

```
for (int i = 0; i <  legend.Colors().length-1; i++) {
 .....
 .....
 }
```

**Steps 4**

Then you have to take one layout horizontal or vertical. You have to get legends color codes and legends lable and according to legends length create layout and label.
 Code sample is given below

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms_left_layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        parms_left_layout.weight = 1F;
        LinearLayout left_layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        left_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        left_layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        left_layout.setLayoutParams(parms_left_layout);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms_legen_layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                20, 20);
        parms_legen_layout.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);
        LinearLayout legend_layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        legend_layout.setLayoutParams(parms_legen_layout);
        legend_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        legend_layout.setBackgroundColor(colorcodes[i]);
        left_layout.addView(legend_layout);

        TextView txt_unit = new TextView(context);
        txt_unit.setText(legend.getLabel(i));
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: can you share sample app

Answer (score 4):

Set wrap content support only Legends postion when legend position is
BelowChartLeft, BelowChartRight, BelowChartCenter

```
     Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
        legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_LEFT);
        legend.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

After this set dataset

```
 pieChart.setData(pieData)
```

it will work fine

Answer (score 3):

```
 Legend l = pieChart.getLegend();
 l.setPosition(LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_LEFT);
 l.setXEntrySpace(7f);
 l.setYEntrySpace(0f);
 l.setYOffset(0f);
 l.setDirection(LegendDirection.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
 l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid **clipping of legend values** use the following block of code

```
Legend legend=lineChart.getLegend();
legend.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

**Doc (for legend):**

```
/**
     * Should the legend word wrap? / this is currently supported only for:
     * BelowChartLeft, BelowChartRight, BelowChartCenter. / note that word
     * wrapping a legend takes a toll on performance. / you may want to set
     * maxSizePercent when word wrapping, to set the point where the text wraps.
     * / default: false
     * 
     * @param enabled
     */
    public void setWordWrapEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mWordWrapEnabled = enabled;
    }
```

To avoid **clipping of x-axis labels** use

```
XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
```

**Doc (for x-axis labels):**

```
/**
     * if set to true, the chart will avoid that the first and last label entry
     * in the chart "clip" off the edge of the chart or the screen
     * 
     * @param enabled
     */
    public void setAvoidFirstLastClipping(boolean enabled) {
        mAvoidFirstLastClipping = enabled;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but first and last data point value are cropped too, any solution?

Comment: @erical Can you please provide a screenshot for your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
Legend l = pieChart.getLegend();
l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
l.setDrawInside(false);
l.setXEntrySpace(4f);
l.setYEntrySpace(0f);
l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long research, I found the solution. The below code solved it.

chart.getLegend().setWordWrapEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the following function available for piecharts

```
piechart.getLegend().setWordWrapEnabled(true);
```